# Drupal 7. Hide exposed form after ajax submit

Tags: ajax, drupal-7, view, drupal-exposed-filter

How hide filter exposed form after success send?
Form in block and work with ajax.
Help pleace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved! :)**

```js
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.betterExposedFilters = {
   attach: function(context, settings) {  
      $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, jqXHR, settings) {
        $('.view-filters').hide();
      });
  }}
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks [Matoeil](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/jquery-script-on-view-not-working-when-filtering-with-ajax-on-better-exposed?answertab=votes#tab-top)!